# Not able to run the test case with mvn integration-test

Tags: selenium, selenium-webdriver, jbehave

I use following command to run my selinium web driver , JBehave test case.

mvn integration-test -Dbrowser="firefox" -Dwebdriver.firefox.driver="C:\Program Files (x86)\Mozilla Firefox\firefox.exe"

But I'm getting following error.

> [WARNING] Failed to run batch
>   org.jbehave.core.embedder.PerformableTree$SomethingHappened@7a5e865e: org.jbehave.web.selenium.DelegatingWebDriverProvider$DelegateWebDriverNotFound:
>   WebDriver has not been found for this thread.
>   Please verify you are using the correct WebDriverProvider, with the appropriate credentials if using remote access, e.g. to SauceLabs: -DSAUCE_USERNAM
>   E=xxxxxx -DSAUCE_ACCESS_KEY=xxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxx
>   [INFO] Generating reports view to 'D:\workspace\aws-spend\awsspend-jbehave-selinium\target\jbehave' using formats '[stats, console, txt, html, xml]' a
>   nd view properties '{navigator=ftl/jbehave-navigator.ftl, views=ftl/jbehave-views.ftl, reports=ftl/jbehave-reports.ftl, nonDecorated=ftl/jbehave-repor
>   t-non-decorated.ftl, decorated=ftl/jbehave-report-decorated.ftl, maps=ftl/jbehave-maps.ftl}'

Answer (score 0):

It seems that it can't find the firefox driver. Download the `FireFox WebDriver` as described here: https://code.google.com/p/selenium/wiki/FirefoxDriver 
and use the described properties.

Your are using

```
-Dwebdriver.firefox.driver="C:\Program Files (x86)\Mozilla Firefox\firefox.exe"
```

but reagarding to the page the correct property for defining the location is

```
webdriver.firefox.bin
```

so I assume it should be something like

```
-Dwebdriver.firefox.bin="C:\Program Files (x86)\Mozilla Firefox\firefox.exe"
```

assuming that the `firefox.exe` is your downloaded `WebDriver` and not a regular Firefox installation.